# Split a value in a cell and add to a newly created row in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataset where I need to evaluate multiple entries with the same id code and split a cell value in the last row if a set of conditionals are met.

Condtionals = the final row for that id has action=="l" & time >60.

If this conditional is met I would like to change the row action <- "e", and time <- 60. The amount of time exceeding 60 should be placed in a newly formed row below. The column contents for the new row should be identical to the parent row except action=="l" & time==original value - 60).

Sample data set

```
id <- c("12_1","12_1","12_1","12_2","12_2","12_2")
action <- c("l","d","l","l","d","l")
time <- c(15,45,90,20,30,61)
dtfrm <-data.frame(cbind(id,action,time))
```

Test dataframe

```
    id action time
1 12_1      l   15
2 12_1      d   45
3 12_1      l   90
4 12_2      l   20
5 12_2      d   30
6 12_2      l   61
```

I would like the transformed dataframe to look like this

```
    id action time
1 12_1      l   15
2 12_1      d   45
3 12_1      e   60
4 12_1      l   30
5 12_2      l   20
6 12_2      d   30
7 12_2      e   60
8 12_2      l    1
```

Eventually I will have more complex conditionals to evaluate but I am trying to start simple and work my way up the more complex conditionals needed to massage this data set into working order. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write a function that operates on one group "id":

```
process.one <- function(df) {
  n <- nrow(df)
  last.action <- df$action[n]
  last.time   <- df$time[n]
  if (last.action == "l" & last.time > 60) {
    next.row <- df[n, ]
    next.row$action = "l"
    next.row$time   = last.time - 60
    df <- rbind(df, next.row)
    df$action[n] <- "e"
    df$time[n]   <- 60
  }
  df
}
```

Then slit/apply/combine using `plyr`:

```
ddply(dtfrm, "id", process.one)
#     id action time
# 1 12_1      l   15
# 2 12_1      d   45
# 3 12_1      e   60
# 4 12_1      l   30
# 5 12_2      l   20
# 6 12_2      d   30
# 7 12_2      e   60
# 8 12_2      l    1
```

Also make sure your data.frame does not have factors otherwise appending to it can be problematic. At the top, it should be:

```
dtfrm <- data.frame(id, action, time, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My real dataframe has 46 columns. Is there a way to "copy" all the values from the previous row and only change action and time or will I need to add these additional column names and how I want them populated into the formula?

Comment: thanks for working this up. I thought with this start I could mod your answer and work in my additional conditionals but I am having some trouble. I now need to evaluate the row above and only modify if that row action=="d". I thought i could create previous.action <- df$action_time[n-1], and add another & previous.action == "d" to the conditional but it is not working. Tips?

Comment: Like you said, but it should be `previous.action <- df$action[n-1]`. This also assumes each group has at least two rows, if it is not the case, you will need to check that `n > 1`.

Comment: n does equal 1 on more than a few occasions, should that not evaluate to NA therefor still allowing the function to run when previous.action=="NA"?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit involved, but this should do it:

```
# fix the time column, it should be numeric
dtfrm[, "time"] <- as.numeric(as.character(dtfrm[, "time"]))

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(cbind(dtfrm, rowid=seq(nrow(dtfrm))), key="id")

# identify which rows need modification
DT[, needsMod := FALSE]
DT[unique(DT[, "id", with=FALSE])
   ,  needsMod := {L <- length(action); (action[L] == "l" && time[L] > 60)  }
   , by=id
   , mult="last"]

# append new rows
DT <- setkey(rbind(DT, 
       DT[c(needsMod), list(id, action, time=time-60, rowid=rowid+1e-2, needsMod=!needsMod)]), 
       id, rowid)

# modify the identified rows
DT[c(needsMod), c("action", "time") := list("e", 60)]

# optionally remove added columns, though personally, I would keep some form of rowid
DT[ , c("needsMod", "rowid") := NULL]
DT

#      id action time
# 1: 12_1      l   15
# 2: 12_1      d   45
# 3: 12_1      e   60
# 4: 12_1      l   30
# 5: 12_2      l   20
# 6: 12_2      d   30
# 7: 12_2      e   60
# 8: 12_2      l    1
```